# Why would one want to compile multiple .cpp files to the same executable?

Tags: compiling, c, c++

Why would you do

```
g++ -Wall -I/usr/local/include/thrift *.cpp -lthrift -o something
```

instead of:

```
g++ -Wall -I/usr/local/include/thrift -c Something.cpp -o something.o
g++ -Wall -I/usr/local/include/thrift -c Something_server.cpp -o server.o
g++ -Wall -I/usr/local/include/thrift -c your_thrift_file_constants.cpp -o constants.o
g++ -Wall -I/usr/local/include/thrift -c your_thrift_file_types.cpp -o types.o
```

and then:

```
g++ -L/usr/local/lib -lthrift *.o -o Something_server
```

Am I right that the first step does essentially the same thing as the second sequence?

Also, to make them identical should `something` be `Something_server` in the first line?

Comment: Shouldn’t your question be the other way round? As it is, the answer is trivial: “because it’s five times shorter”.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You're right that you'll end up with the same executable at the end (albeit with a different name); in the first case gcc will actually create a bunch of temporary object files that it removes after linking, versus the second case where you're making the object files yourself.

The main reason to do things the second way is to allow for **incremental building**. After you've compiled your project once, say you change `Something.cpp`. The only object file affected is `something.o` -- there's no reason to waste time rebuilding the others. A build system like `make` would recognize that and only rebuild `something.o` before linking all the object files together.